# meteor-leaflet : retrieve single doc per feature from collection over iteration?

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet

Until now I had a pure JS implementation of **LeafletJS**. 
Now I'm using [meteor-leaflet package](https://github.com/bevanhunt/meteor-leaflet) (and its demo) to get a map integrated, data coming from **GeoJSON files**.
I define some style depending data coming from GeoJSON features and this works fine.

```
function style(feature) {
    criteria = feature.properties.myField;  // Current implementation, grabbed from feature fields into GeoJSON files
    return {
       fillColor: getColor(criteria)
    };
}
...
var myGeojsonLayer = L.geoJson.ajax("myGeojsonFile.geojson", {style: style, onEachFeature:onEachFeature});  
myGeojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

Now I'd like to define style depending **data coming from a MongoDB collection**.

I'm new to Meteor and I don't know the best way to get this. I tried to use **findOne()** over iteration of all features but it failed.
I'm a bit aware of issues due to unavailable data at startup like explained [here](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) but I'm unsure it is linked.

Does anyone would have example of how to query (**NOT by _id**) collection at startup (ie waiting data available) for **single document per feature** over iteration ?

Thanks.
Tom

Comment: Well there is a lot of design decisions to make first in the situation you describe. If your data is hard-coded in `.geojson` files instead of being made available through DB, why not encoding the style along with it? Why not transferring the data into DB? We could also imagine re-styling the GeoJSON layers once style collection documents are available on the Client. etc.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. You're right, this implies design stuff. Currently data is in .geojson but I'd like to move it to DB in order to make them updatable (and then making style dynamic with it). Actually my question results from a lack of experience with Meteor philosophy. I may have found a way, but not sure it is correct way for doing ths in Meteor style. Still working  on it and testing.